# Php double database entry in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

My site accepts donations for charities. People donate and then their donations along with support messages are shown on the donation page.

I have two problems.

1. Problem is that **sometimes** but not all the time the donations are entered twice to the database which means they show twice on the front end as well.

[Screenshot of double database entry with same transaction id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knFq5.png)

[Screenshot of double entry on the front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bb4R.png)

Below is the code that adds the donations and "cheers" messages to the database. I can't figure out why the entries occur twice sometimes but not always. When I look at the time stamps the entries are minutes apart so I thought the user might have refreshed the page but I don't know how to prevent that.

2. Problem: The site uses wp eCommerce plugin to handle the donations. The donations are added to the wp eCommerces purchase log but they are missing the donation amounts.

[Screenshot of purchase log with missing donation amounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iEY5.png)

I'm using Wordpress 4.8.4 and [wp eCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-e-commerce/) to handle the donations.
Php version: 5.6.27
Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73

The donations are entered correctly most of the time but these double entries are driving me mad and I can't figure out why they happen. Hope someone with more knowledge can help. Thanks in advance.

Below is the code for adding the donations to the database and the purchase log.
The comments in the code are by the plugin developer and me. I can't reach the original developer so I'm trying to sort through this myself. I'm more of a web designer but have some basic knowledge of php and mysql.

```
/** Function to add cheers when transaction is completed **/

function kd_add_cheers () {
global $wpdb;
global $kd_table;
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
$stamp = $_GET['STAMP'];
$session = $_GET['sessionid'];
$transaction = $stamp.$session;
$t1 = $prefix."wpsc_submited_form_data";
$t2 = $prefix."wpsc_purchase_logs";
$t3 = $kd_table;
$t4 = $prefix."postmeta"; //remove if doesnt work edit by oliver

// Set these in production!!!

$firstname_field = '2';
$lastname_field = '3';
$message_field = '22';
$recipient_field = '29';
$price_field = '19';
$anonymous_field = '23';



$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$t3." WHERE `transaction`=".$transaction;
$cheers = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

// Make sure this transaction gets submitted only once
// (To prevent page refresh re-injection)
if (empty($cheers)) {
    $sql = "
        SELECT ".$t1.".form_id, ".$t1.".value FROM ".$t1."
        INNER JOIN ".$t2." 
        ON ".$t1.".log_id = ".$t2.".id
        WHERE ".$t2.".sessionid = ".$session." 
        AND ".$t2.".id = ".$stamp;

    $posts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    if (!empty($posts)) {

        $insert = array();
        $insert['transaction'] = $transaction;


        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $insert['field_'.$post->form_id] = $post->value;
            $insert['field_price'] = $post->totalprice;
        }

        if ($insert['field_'.$recipient_field] != '' &&   trim($insert['field_'.$recipient_field]) != '') {


            if (isset($insert['field_'.$anonymous_field]) && $insert['field_'.$anonymous_field] == 'Kyllä') {
                $donator = '';
            }
            else $donator = $insert['field_'.$firstname_field]." ".$insert['field_'.$lastname_field];

            $msg = esc_attr($insert['field_'.$message_field]);
            $msg = str_replace(':', '', $msg);
            $msg = str_replace(';', '', $msg);
            $msg = str_replace('"', '', $msg);
            $msg = str_replace(')', '', $msg);
            $msg = str_replace('(', '', $msg);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$t3." (`from`, `content`, `for`, `transaction`, `price`) VALUES 
            ('".esc_attr($donator)."', '".$msg."', '".$insert['field_'.$recipient_field]."', '".$insert['transaction']."', '".$insert['field_'.$price_field]."')";
            $inserted = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

            if ($inserted) return true;

        }

    }
}
}

function kd_update_transaction_status() {
global $wpdb;
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
$stamp = $_GET['STAMP'];
$session = $_GET['sessionid'];
$table = $prefix."wpsc_purchase_logs";

$sql = "UPDATE ".$table." SET `processed`=2,`email_sent`=1 WHERE `sessionid` = '".$session."' AND `id` = '".$stamp."'";

$inserted = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
if ($inserted) return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second question I can't answer, since I don't know enough about wordpress. But for the first one I can see one or two things that might cause the problem.

First of all I noticed that these duplicate entries were inserted *6 minutes apart*. This means that this script ran two times, making it obvious that `$cheers` is always empty, therefore inserting a new entry into $kd_table.

Now you can ask, why is $cheers empty? Because the Query is not correct. You did not put single quotes around the `$transaction` value in the WHERE clause.

change this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$t3." WHERE `transaction`=".$transaction;
```

to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$t3." WHERE `transaction`='".$transaction."'";
```

and check if `$cheers` is not empty when calling this script for a second time.

Comment: Wow. Thank you! I didn't figure I would get a response so quickly.
I changed the code like you suggested.
I will update the status of my question after the site receives some donations succesfully. 
Stackoverflow really has an awesome community. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. I would suggest you test this yourself, since it could well be something else that causes the bug, something not included in this question. It could be that the transaction column is an integer and would not need these singlequotes that I mentioned. Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: I checked and the transaction column is defined as varchar. Below is the code from the plugins installation part:

Comment: /** Install **/

     function kd_install() {
    global $wpdb;
   global $kd_table;
 $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $kd_table . " (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `from` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `for` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `transaction` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (`id`) 
  )";
 require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
 dbDelta($sql);
    }

    register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'kd_install');